# Passing a variable in view , to show details

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, model-view-controller

> This is my view with session details. Now i also want to pass '$result' variable which contains details from my database so that i can display them in my view , but i am unable to understand , how to pass variable.

```
$this->load->view('user/appconfig/masteradmin',array('data'=>$data));
```

Comment: it's all outlined in the view docs.

Comment: `$this->load->view('user/appconfig/masteradmin',array('data'=>$data,'result' => $result));`

Comment: What are you passing? data has to be stated as something like $data['title']  = "Title"; Then pass it through the view like $this->load->view('user/appconfig/masteradmin', $data);

Answer (score 1):

You can pass **"$result"** variable directly in view

ex for :-

```
 $this->load->view('user/appconfig/masteradmin',$result);
```

in view you can use like :-

```
<?=$name?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create a separate variable like

```
    $data=array(
    'db'=>'',
    'user'=>'',
    'host'=>'');
    $data['login_by']='';
 and then pass to view as
$this->load->view('user/appconfig/masteradmin',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass multiple variables data to view, you have write code in controller:

```
$data['data']=$data;
$data['result']=$result;

$this->load->view('user/appconfig/masteradmin',$data);
```

And you can write code to show the data like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $result['name']?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

May be this is useful to you.